# Hi. i'm trying to build a newsletter using action mailer. Unfortunately i'm stuck when i'm trying to send emails to each users registered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, mailer

the preview isn't working and keep getting different errors.

My schema.rb looks like this

```
ActiveRecord::Schema[7.0].define(version: 2022_12_31_110010) do
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "emailadress"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

My user model looks like this:

```
def send_daily
    users = User.all(params[:id])
    users.each. do |user|
      UserMailer.send_daily_newsletter(user).deliver_now
    end
    redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Newsletter envoyée.'
end
```

my User.Mailer looks like this:

```
    class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
      def send_daily_newsletter(user)
      @user = user
      mail(to: @user.emailadress, subject: 'Votre fait historique quotidien')
     end
    end
```

and my mailer preview looks like this:

```
class UserMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def send_daily_newsletter
    user = User.all # Ou tout autre utilisateur de votre choix pour la prévisualisation
    UserMailer.send_daily_newsletter(user)
  end
end
```

I keep getting the following error :

```
undefined method `emailadress' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 14, emailadress: "thomasandrieu1997@gmail.com", created_at: "2023-07-02 10:32:46.657533000 +0000", updated_at: "2023-07-02 10:32:46.657533000 +0000">, #<User id: 15, emailadress: "than1544@colorad.edu", created_at: "2023-07-02 11:43:17.121218000 +0000", updated_at: "2023-07-02 11:43:17.121218000 +0000">]>
```

Do you guys have any recommendation on what I should change to be able to visualise correctly the emails in the preview ?? thanks a lot !

Comment: First of all, don't use so much bold. It makes your question harder to read.

Comment: Second, check your spelling...are you sure the fieled is called `emailadress`? If so, I still suggest you correct the spelling.

Comment: Hi. Sorry, first time I post a question. I'm not use to it. emailadress emailadress is the email associated to each user. I should correct the spelling you're right

Comment: It's seems to work for one recipient. But my method to send an email to multiple user in my user controller doesn't seem to work.

Comment: "adress" is spelled wrong. If you use the misspelling consistently everwhere, then the computer doesn't care, but correct spelling will make it easier for human readers, including yourself in several weeks.

Answer (score 2):

You get that error in your `UserMailerPreview` because you assign `User.all` to `user` which means you are passing an `ActiveRecord::Relation` and not a single record to your newsletter method. Which than fails in this line in your mailer: `mail(to: @user.emailadress, ...`

To fix this issue change

```
class UserMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def send_daily_newsletter
    user = User.all # Ou tout autre utilisateur de votre choix pour la prévisualisation
    UserMailer.send_daily_newsletter(user)
  end
end
```

to

```
class UserMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def send_daily_newsletter
    user = User.first # or `last` or `find(1)` or any other method returning a single user
    UserMailer.send_daily_newsletter(user)
  end
end
```

And another issue you will need to fix is method in your controller (?):

```
def send_daily
  users = User.all(params[:id])
  users.each. do |user|
    UserMailer.send_daily_newsletter(user).deliver_now
  end
  redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Newsletter envoyée.'
end
```

`User.all(params[:id])` is raise an error because the `all` method doesn't accept arguments. It should just be `User.all` without the `params[:id]`.

Answer (score 1):

you have the issue in the following line

```
class UserMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def send_daily_newsletter
    user = User.all # Ou tout autre utilisateur de votre choix pour la prévisualisation
    UserMailer.send_daily_newsletter(user)
  end
end

  class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
      def send_daily_newsletter(user)
      @user = user
      mail(to: @user.emailadress, subject: 'Votre fait historique quotidien')
     end
    end
```

in UserMailerPreview you have
`user = User.all` which will give you all the users
now if you use `user.emailaddress` it will raise error as **user** is the **list of users** and that list does not have emailaddress.

if you **loop through** it, then you will get the emailaddress.

it's better to use the plural as a variable name when you will expecting multiple results from the database.

try to use like following which may resolve your confusion
 `users = User.all`

Comment: thanks a lot. it's seems to work! unfortunately, it only sends email to the first adress email. if i want my preview to show emails sent to all each users i should loop like i did in my controller ?

Comment: @Tholas Yes. Use `each` to loop over all the users.